# Change right Bar ButtonItem from 'Save' to 'Done'

Tags: ios, uinavigationitem

i have a NavigationItem with a right BarButtonItem and it's Identifier - initially - 'Save' to save entities i create on the view.

In my view i use a DatePicker. If this DatePicker is visible, the 'Save' Button should not be a 'Save' Button but a 'Done' Button. If the DatePicker is not visible, the 'Done' Button should change to 'Save' again.

I understand the identifier in Interface Builder like that localization is included. So I think, i can't just change the Title, right?

Can you tell me how to change the button from 'Save' to 'Done' or how i do it otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would normally do here is to create another `UIBarButtonItem` instance with title 'Done' and save it along with the normal 'Save' button as instance variables in my view controller. Then when the 'Done' button needs to be shown I would call `setRightBarButtonItem:animated:` on the `UINavigationItem` to change the button and the same to set it back to the 'Save' button when required.

I think that's generally better than just changing the title as they are distinct actions so it makes more sense for them to be wired up to different action methods.

Answer (score 3):

matt is right - have two buttons and swap them in / out as needed. Although I expect you could keep track of one button and change the title; why would you do that when you also have two different actions that you wish to perform?

```
 saveBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Save" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(save:)];

 doneBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(done:)];
```

Comment: thank you, took me a bit after matts answer. My implementation does only have one action. It's behavior is set by the tag of the Button.

Comment: Behaviour by tag, when you can just set a target action on a button directly? That's horrible!

Comment: yeah - KISS is the way to go.... my advice would be to keep the internals of an action to do one thing (should be possible in the vast majority of cases). After all is your action named saveOrDone: ? I'm guessing not. Far better to have two action methods, a save: and a done: